# Getting the maximum allowed value for a member variable in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, decltype

I am using an external library which defines a struct with an unsigned int C-style array:

```
struct Foo
{
    unsigned int bar[8];
}
```

In my code, I want to get the numeric_limits::max() for that type in order to check out of bounds values, and avoid passing overflowed values to the library.

So I do :

```
auto n = Foo().bar[0];
if(myBar > std::numeric_limits<decltype (n)>::max())
{
    error("The Foo library doesn't support bars that large");
    return false;
}
```

This works, but is there a more elegant c++11 way not implying declaring a variable? If I use `decltype(Foo().bar[0])` I have an error, as this returns a reference type, which `numeric_limits` doesn't like.

Answer (score 2):

For lvalue expressions like `Foo().bar[0]`, [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) yields type `T&`, i.e. lvalue-reference type.

You can remove the reference part by using [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

```
std::numeric_limits<std::remove_reference<decltype(Foo().bar[0])>::type>
```

Comment: Ah perfect! This does the job perfectly and I can easily put this in a template function.

Comment: @galinette For templates you might need `typename` keyword like `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(...)>::type`.

Comment: `std::decay` is a good alternative (remove constness also).

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this :

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {
  unsigned int bar[8];
};

int main() {

  auto max_val = std::numeric_limits<std::remove_all_extents_t<decltype(std::declval<Foo>().bar)>>::max();


  return 0;
}
```

[`std::remove_all_extents`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_all_extents/) removes the "array part" of your member. The advantage is that this will work on simple `int`, `int []`, and multi-dimensional arrays too. As you don't make use of the `operator[]`, you avoid the "reference problem" as well.

[`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) allows to determine the type of `bar` if you don't have an instance at hand.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to @songyuanyao's answer, you can avoid having to instantiate `Foo` by using `std::declval`, like so:

```
if (myBar > std::numeric_limits<std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval <Foo>().bar [0])>::type>::max())
...
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CcG3aFyno0NlmStI)